# rep function in R

Tags: r, rep

When I perform:

```
rep(1:4, rep(4,4))
```

I get

```
1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4
```

which is expected. But then when I try to fix the length to 16(which is the length of the output) as follows:

```
rep(1:4, rep(4,4), length.out = 16)
```

I get

```
1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4
```

which is weird. I think both of these commands should perform the same function. Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Comment: have you read the help page `?rep`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `?rep`

> ‘length.out’ may be given in place of ‘times’, in which case ‘x’
>        is repeated as many times as is necessary to create a vector of
>        this length.  If both are given, ‘length.out’ takes priority and
>        ‘times’ is ignored.

Comment: But look at the `each` argument to see if that gives the output that you want.

Comment: Thanks GSee. I did not read the whole help documentation. However,what was troubling me was that if I specify **rep(1:4, each = 4, length = 20)**, then I get **1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 1 1 1 1** but I guess it turns out that if **each=4** is replaced with **rep(4,4)**, then the print method is different, even though both each and rep() should fulfill the same purpose here. Thanks!

Comment: You need to read `?rep` thoroughly. What do you mean by the `print` method? `rep(1:4, each = rep(4,4), length = 20)` gives you a warning which is self explanatory (especially if you read the help!)

Answer (score -2):

`rep(1:4,,rep(4,4),length.out=16)` will give the result you are looking for. A simpler way to write this is `rep(1:4,,16,4)`.

Comment: technically correct, but ugh! much better practice to use named arguments rather than placeholders (`,,`)

Comment: I'm not sure this is even *technically* correct.  It works on the R instance on the computer I'm typing this on (a couple years old: 2.15), but I get a warning message that suggests that it's only by accident ("Warning: first element used of 'each' argument").  Also, the order of parameters beyond the first two isn't documented at all, so I don't think there's any guarantee it won't break in a future revision.